# Column Validation Formula - Compare other column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have here two column, Status and Date.

The Status is a choice field (PAST DUE AND PRESENT).

I want to have a formula for the Date Column to check once the data for Status is Past Due, error message will display on the Date Column once they pick a past dates.

I'm trying to do something like this on the column validation: Sudo code below

```
If Status = "Past Due"
and Date < "Today"
DisplayMessage = "Cannot Select Past Dates"
```

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated Date column in list which has formula as below:

```
=IF([Status]="Past Due", "Cannot Select Dates as Status is Past Due", [Today])
```

Comment: Remember, SharePoint is not Excel so [Today] calculation is static (not updating tomorrow)